# backgroundImage images throws console errors on enabled CDN

Tags: sxa

We are facing issues on background image while using CDN.

We have SXA website and enabled Background image but its throws console error while enabling azure cdn. Found that extra "/" is adding before the cdn image url.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/enable-adding-a-background-image-to-a-rendering.html

[image]

[image]

With CDN

```
background image: style="background-image: url('/https://sxazureqacdn.azureedge.net/-/media/Project/sxasite/sxa-Site/Hero/headerBackground-100.jpg?rev=a61a8de77daa45b098d2d16d0ba20673');"
```

Without CDN

```
background image: style="background-image: url('/-/media/Project/sxasite/sxa-Site/Hero/headerBackground-100.jpg');"
```

[image]

Please help me to fix this kind of issue.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me... have you contacted Support?

Comment: I created a support ticket but for security reasons I cannot share all the details with support team.